# UrlGenerationError missing required keys [:id]

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a sign up where I want to send an email activation to the user. However I have a nested attribute, where a user belongs to a company.

error:

```
CompaniesSignupTest#test_valid_signup_information:
ActionView::Template::Error: No route matches {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"account_activations", :email=>"user@example.com", :id=>nil} missing required keys: [:id]
```

Now this works:

```
def create
 log_in @company.users.first
 redirect_to root_path
end
```

however when I try to send an email:

```
def create
 UserMailer.account_activation(@company.users.first).deliver_now
 redirect_to root_url
end
```

I get an error where it says it can't find the id. Which I find odd, as it's able to find the ID on a log in, but not here.

Here's the request parameters:

```
"company"=>{"users_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"first_name"=>"eorkge",
 "last_name"=>"okerogkeogk",
 "email"=>"egreoke@ergokeoke.com",
 "password"=>"[FILTERED]"}},
 "name"=>"oekgoekg"},
 "commit"=>"Create Company"}
```

and the route:

```
<%= link_to "Activate account", edit_account_activation_url(@user.activation_token,
                                                email: @user.email) %>
```

and mailers/user_mailer:

```
  def account_activation(user)
    @user = user
    mail to: user.email, subject: "Account activation"
  end
```

routes:

```
  resources :account_activations, only: [:edit]
```

results of bundle exec rake routes | grep account_activation

```
edit_account_activation GET    /account_activations/:id/edit(.:format) account_activations#edit
```

**note:**
when I check preview mailer I am able to get it working. It renders the URL in plain text like this:

```
http://localhost:3000/account_activations/qsdBBow-dcKI00Jf3awu5Q/edit?email=demo%40demo.com
```

and the user_mailer_preview method is:

```
  def account_activation
    user = User.first
    user.activation_token = User.new_token
    UserMailer.account_activation(user)
  end
```

Comment: Could you share the entry from your routes file for the `edit_account_activation_url` route?

Comment: done, I've gone ahead and updated!

Comment: Thanks! Have you tried passing the id explicitly? — `edit_account_activation_url(id: @user.activation_token, email: @user.email)`

Comment: tried it, no luck :/ !

Comment: Can you paste result of `bundle exec rake routes | grep account_activation` run in console?

Comment: Also what @polarblau makes no sense I think because ID is missing, not activation token, right?

Comment: @MichalSzyndel updated

Comment: So what is the error then you did what @polarblau suggested? Is it different? Can you paste a log for that request?

Comment: no changes when I added the id:

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91955/discussion-between-sebastian-jennings-almnes-and-michal-szyndel).

Comment: I have nearly the exact same issue, working through Hartl's Ruby on Rails Tutorial. The chat link iimmediately above gives me `page not found` even though I have >20 rep. How did you solve this, @SebastianJenningsAlmnes ?

Answer (score 0):

The same problem happened to me and the following worked fine.

Instead of just passing the object (`@instance variable`) to the `link_to` helper as I would do for a regular `route_path`, I explicitly mentioned the `:id` in the `route_url`.

In your case it would be:

```
<%= link_to 'Activate account', edit_account_activation_url(id: @user.id)  %>
```

Answer (score -1):

As mentioned in  previous answer I wrote, the problem here will be that you're not assigning the `id` param explicitly:

```
edit_account_activation_url(@user.activation_token, email: @user.email)
```

In the path helper, Rails will take passed objects and use the appropriate attributes to form the route.

Rails is a logical program, it's not magic; it will be looking for `id` and `email` from `@user`, in the route you posted.

Because you want to use `activation_token` in place of `id`, you'll be best using the following:

```
edit_account_activation_url(id: @user.activation_token, email: @user.email)
```

This should work from looking at both your previous question and this one. Your previous question also showed the `@user` object to have an ID, thus showing your thoughts about it not being present to be incorrect.

Comment: Is there a message that the hash value of the `id` key needs to respond to? I'm still getting a complaint about `id` being `nil`.

Comment: It turned out to be a `nil` created by not using `self.` when assigning a virtual attribute (see [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39990052/5353461) to this question). Why is the `self.` required? It seems redundant but is obviously important.

Comment: Where are you having to use `self.`?

Comment: I needed to use `self.variable = assigned_value` because otherwise `variable` was a local which would then go out of scope.

Answer (score -1):

The first argument to the url helper is used as the `:id`, which should not be `nil`.

Your first argument (namely `@user.activation_token`) is `nil`.

---

It looks like your code is based upon [Chapter 11 of the Ruby on Rails Tutorial](https://www.railstutorial.org/book/account_activation).

I had the same issue, and for me, a `nil`-hunt gave some enlightenment. I changed:

```
  # Creates and assigns the activation token and digest
  def create_activation_digest
    activation_token = User.new_token
    activation_digest = User.digest activation_token
  end
```

to:

```
  # Creates and assigns the activation token and digest
  def create_activation_digest
    self.activation_token = User.new_token
    self.activation_digest = User.digest activation_token
  end
```

The plain`activation_token` is a local variable shadowing a object attribute of the same name. The local variable will go out of scope at the end of the `create_activation_digest` method, leaving the object attribute untouched, and in my case, still `nil`.

To assign to an object attribute, ruby requires the `self.` prefix on the attribute name.